# What are the main differences between HDF schema registry and the Confluent one?

Tags: apache-kafka, hortonworks-data-platform, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I was wondering about the differences of the kafka embebed in the HDF suite and the Confluent one, specifically the schema registry tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://registry-project.readthedocs.io/en/latest/competition.html

The Hortonworks schema registry depends on a Mysql or Postgres database (supposedly this is pluggable, so you could write your own storage layer) to store its schemas while the Confluent one stores schemas directly in Kafka. Therefore there's more infrastructure to manage with Hortonworks implementation.

The Hortonworks one supposedly has some plugin mechanism so that it'll support the Confluent serialization format, but I've not seen it used in practice. It also has pluggable schema storage, but I've not seen anything except Avro used in it.

The Hortonworks one has its own web UI and rich editor, compared to the Confluent one, where you're limited to third-party tools or purchasing a license for Confluent Control Center.

Hortonworks aims to provide integrations with Spark, Nifi, SMM, Storm, Atlas, possibly Ranger, and other components of their HDF stack. Confluent Schema Registry support in those tools is all community driven.

Comment: Also, I see that the confluent schema registry provides monitoring out of the box, is there any such mechanism in the hortonworks one? I'm trying to setup jmx metrics in my HDP schema registry, its a dockerized setup. However Im not sure how to proceed further, would you be able to help with the same?

Comment: @mythic Not sure what you mean. All Java applications have monitoring out of the box. This is called JMX, and the Hortonworks Registry does have JMX

Comment: I'm unable to find the config parameters to set for jmx monitoring in the hortonworks schema registry documentation. I may be completely wrong here but I am clueless how to setup jmx monitoring for my Hortonworks schema registry

Comment: I'm struggling to set `SCHEMA_REGISTRY_JMX_OPTS`  in my setup. in which file should this be set? I have the jmx agent jar, but i cant understand how to expose metrics? and where to makr those changes?

Comment: I haven't used the Hortonworks one... That is just an environment variable, though

Comment: sure thanks, I couldn't find anything in the source code which uses the env variables, looks like they dont provide it out of the box. Thanks! :)